# If f(n) = O(n) and g(n) = O(n), prove f(g(n)) = O(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem. Big O is confusing me. Can anyone help me figure it out? `f(n) = O(n)` and `g(n) = O(n)`. How can I prove `f(g(n)) = O(n)`?

Comment: Say for example that `f(n) = 2n` and `g(n) = 3n`. Then `f o g (n) = f(g(n)) = 2(3n) = 6n`, which is still `O(n)`. (Not a formal proof, but just some quick intuition for how it might work.)

Comment: @M-Chen-3 how can I turn this into proof?

Comment: @Confused101 Replace `2`, `3` with some constants `a`, `b`, and `=` with `<=`, then use the definition of `O(n)`.

Comment: @dxiv So f(g(n)) <= (ab)n = O(n) Is this correct?

Comment: @Confused101 Right.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `O` definition:

```
f(n) = O(n) => f(n) < c1*n for n > n0 and c1 is constant.
g(n) = O(n) => g(n) < c2*n for n > n1 and c2 is constant.
```

Hence, we have:

```
f(g(n)) < c1 * g(n) < c1 * c2 * n for n > max(n0, n1) => 
f(g(n)) < c3 * n for n > max(n0, n1) and c3 is constant.
```

The latter is the definition of `O` and means `f(g(n)) = O(n)`.